# Find unreachable loose objects in a repo

Tags: git, garbage-collection, libgit2

We are developing some software, using libgit2, which is automatically storing some data in a git repository. It is doing this very frequently. To keep the performance up the software is also running `git gc --auto` very frequently.
Now we got the message

> error: The last gc run reported the following. Please correct the root cause and remove .git/gc.log.
>   Automatic cleanup will not be performed until the file is removed.
>
> warning: There are too many unreachable loose objects; run 'git prune' to remove them.

sure I could just go the repository and run `git prune` and remote the `gc.log` or I could let the software execute `git gc --prune=all` instead.

But I guess the software is creating some git objects which are not needed. How can I inspect how many and which object in a repository are not reachable?

---

Edit: With `git fsck` I get:

```
$ git fsck --unreachable
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (7568/7568), done.
Checking connectivity: 13781, done.
```

From this I don't really know, which objects actually are loose.

Comment: See https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck.html

Comment: `git fsck --unreachable` just returns: `Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done. Checking objects: 100% (7568/7568), done. Checking connectivity: 13781, done.` so I don't really know, which objects are actually loose

Comment: Since most commits are reachable from reflog heads, add `--no-reflogs`. Besides, by "loose" I suppose you mean "dangling".

Comment: :-\ also `git fsck --unreachable --no-reflogs` and `git fsck --no-reflogs` just output `Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (7568/7568), done.`

Comment: Then there are no unreachable objects in the repo.

Answer (score 0):

```
git fsck --unreachable --no-reflogs
```

Try using this code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.